# Which waves could be narrow and directional; any other than electromagnetic?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Which waves could be narrow compared to medium where they propagate and be also directional?  Except for electromagnetic. My guess is that we know no such waves/mediums, electromagnetic propagate in such a way due to wave-particle duality.

I could not find the answer via google. The question raised in my mind due to idea to test [Is there any experimental evidence to support the Terrell rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59779/is-there-any-experimental-evidence-to-support-the-terrell-rotation/592414) for waves which are slow compared to electromagnetic and we could evidence the effect.

Comment: "slow compared to electromagnetic ", the wiki article is clear that the effect is a special relativity effect, so how can your question be internally consistent ?

Comment: @anna, some part of effect not due to relativity exclusively, see my answer to question linked in this.